# How to get object from table A with objectId not equal from blackList in table B?

Tags: javascript, database, parse-platform

Help with expression on JavaScript API.

There are two tables:

A

```
objectId
==========
7iOR0cRF9E

8iOR1cRF9V

9iOR1c1F9V

10OR0cRF9E
```

B

```
blackList
==========
[9iOR1c1F9V, 8iOR1cRF9V]
```

How to get object from table A with objectId not equal from blackList in table B?
In a particular case object 7iOR0cRF9E and 10OR0cRF9E

Comment: For those of us that are familiar with JavaScript, but not parse.com, can you provide a self-contained example, e.g., a [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/)?  The JavaScript to compare two lists would be trivial, but there's a lot of context missing here.  For example native Javascript doesn't have "tables", so what does that mean?

Comment: It is important to understand exactly parse.com.

Comment: I would suggest looking at the documentation, specifically the method [`notContainedIn`](https://parse.com/docs/js/api/symbols/Parse.Query.html#notContainedIn) seems to be exactly what you're after.